Reboot in KDE hangs, but `sudo reboot` works
Ubuntu 22.04.
In Plasma/KDE, when I select reboot (or also shutdown), it usually hangs then. Some windows are still open, and I can sometimes even still interact with them (although window decorations are gone, so I cannot move them around anymore). I can also still switch to some other TTY and use the terminal there.

The counter "Restarting in 28 seconds" also froze, i.e. does not continue to count anymore. You see that the taskbar froze just during the animation to fade out, so it's only partly visible.
On the terminal, when I just type sudo reboot (or also sudo shutdown -P now), that works without issues.
What is the problem? How can I debug this? How can I fix this?
